# Conditionals inside the URI body Ansible

Tags: ansible, uri, jinja2

In the following task, I would like to run:
- always param1 + its state;
- param2 + its state just if exists in the value files;

If param2 and its state do not exists in the value file, I would like to continue to run without error since other machines might have param2+its state.

I have tried something like this, but something is not correct:

```
- uri:
      method: PATCH
      url: https://10.10.10.10/api/xyz
      status_code: 200, 201
      force_basic_auth: yes
      user: user
      password: pass
      return_content: yes
      validate_certs: no
      body_format: "json"
      body:
       replace:
         data:
                - param1: ABC
                  state: enabled
                - param2: "{{ param2 | default(omit) }}"
                  state: "{{ state | default(omit) }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameter 2 is optional? Try to render your body as template with the template lookup plugin: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/template.html

You can have conditional blocks etc. in a template and build a body like you would expect it.